Google Docs API + Salesforce
I have a slightly unique/advanced use case. Consider a document stored in Google Docs that I would like to use as a template for generating documents/pdf using Salesforce data. The template will have regular expressions for merge fields, tables, page breaks etc.
Question is, how I can take that template as base in Salesforce, parse it using Apex, let's say Table and Columns. I am not looking for a complete code, just a nudge in the right direction.
For example, can I use Google Document Service in Salesforce for my use case? "https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document"
